# Visual Studio Code opens a new tab inspecting AL objects everytime I press CTRL in a .DAL file

Tags: visual-studio-code, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

As the title says, Visual Studio Code opens a new tab inspecting AL objects everytime I press CTRL in a .DAL file

Here is a short GIF to see it visually what happens when I press CTRL:
[image]

As you can see 2 new tabs open and it's very sad... That becomes the jungle when I try to copy down function names and those kind of routines

Here is a list with all my VSCode extensions but I don't identify any extension that could cause the problem:

```
365businessdevelopment.bdev-al-xml-doc@1.1.7
alexisvt.flutter-snippets@3.0.0
andrzejzwierzchowski.al-code-outline@3.0.47
argutec.argutec-azure-repos@1.2007.15
BattleBas.kivy-vscode@0.5.5
cweijan.vscode-office@3.1.6
Dart-Code.dart-code@3.72.1
Dart-Code.flutter@3.72.0
esbenp.prettier-vscode@10.1.0
frhtylcn.pythonsnippets@1.0.2
martonsagi.al-object-designer@0.2.4
ms-dotnettools.csharp@2.0.436
ms-dotnettools.vscode-dotnet-runtime@1.7.2
ms-dynamics-smb.al@11.6.861323
ms-python.black-formatter@2023.4.1
ms-python.isort@2023.10.1
ms-python.python@2023.14.0
ms-python.vscode-pylance@2023.8.50
ms-toolsai.jupyter@2023.7.1002162226
ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap@1.1.2
ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers@1.0.17
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-cell-tags@0.1.8
ms-toolsai.vscode-jupyter-slideshow@0.1.5
ms-vscode.cpptools@1.17.5
ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack@1.3.0
ms-vscode.cpptools-themes@2.0.0
PKief.material-icon-theme@4.30.1
redhat.vscode-yaml@1.14.0
ritwickdey.LiveServer@5.7.9
tomoki1207.pdf@1.2.2
tushortz.python-extended-snippets@0.0.1
VisualStudioExptTeam.intellicode-api-usage-examples@0.2.8
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode@1.2.30
waldo.crs-al-language-extension@1.5.28
xdebug.php-debug@1.33.0
```

I've also reinstalled AL Object Designer and all AL extensions but it doesn't make any difference..

What else can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the **useInternalNavigation** from the **AL Object Designer** VSCode extension by adding the following line to your project/workspace/user **settings.json**: `"alObjectDesigner.useInternalNavigation": false`.

Alternatively you could disable/uninstall the `martonsagi.al-object-designer` VSCode extension.

EDIT: For anyone else who is looking to solve a similar problem (which might occure in the very future), you can narrow it down by opening the *Developer Tools* in VSCode: **Help**/**Toggle Developer Tools**. Open the **Console** tab and click on the *clear* button (`CTRL+L`). Then call the corresponding scenario (in this case the unwanted opening of definition in a new tab) and view the log of the console. This way you can find out which extension caused the problem.

Comment: big thanks, it was very painful to code everytime with tabs opening... i got to leave and walk around to take fresh air sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Open Definition In New Tab` to `true` in your user settings:

[image]

Comment: after changing that setting and restart it still opens new tabs when pressing CTRL key :(